# Can namespaced modules handle mutations to the root namespace?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuex-modules

Consider the following scenario.

I have two namespaced modules: `moduleA` and `moduleB`. They both follow a similar pattern:

```
export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: defaultState(),
  actions: {
    // ...
  },
  mutations: {
    [SET_DATA] (state, data) {
      state.data = data
    }
  }
}
```

I then want to be able to reset all of my modules with one action. I commit a mutation "APP_RESET" in the root namespace:

```
commit(APP_RESET, null, { root: true})
```

At this point, I would have added something like this to each of my modules:

```
[APP_RESET] (state) {
  Object.assign(state, defaultState())
}
```

However, the mutations being handled are now:

`moduleA`: `moduleA`/SET_DATA, `moduleA`/APP_RESET

`moduleB`: `moduleB`/SET_DATA, `moduleB`/APP_RESET

Is it possible to set up my namespace modules, such that they can handle the following?

`moduleA`: `moduleA`/SET_DATA, APP_RESET

`moduleB`: `moduleB`/SET_DATA, APP_RESET

Answer (score 0):

I've found my answer. I didn't think to set up actions on the root namespace. E.g.

From non-namespaced context:

```
dispatch(APP_RESET)
```

In each of my modules:

```
[APP_RESET]: {
    root: true,
    handler ({commit}) {
        commit(RESET_MODULE_A)
    }
}
```

From namespaced context:

```
dispatch(APP_RESET)
```

In each of my modules:

```
['namespaceOfDispatcherModule/' + APP_RESET]: {
    root: true,
    handler ({commit}) {
        commit(RESET_MODULE_A)
    }
}
```